# Solving kuramato model using RK4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am currently trying to solve the kuramato model numerically using the runge-kutta 4th order method. I consider the kuramato model:

$\ddot{\theta_i} = P_i - \alpha\omega_i + K \underset{i \neq j}{\sum}sin(\theta_i - \theta_j)$

I then split the differential equation into two first orders like:

$$\dot{\omega_i} = P_i - \alpha\omega_i + K \underset{i \neq j}{\sum}sin(\theta_i - \theta_j)$$
$$\dot{\theta_i} = \omega_i$$

And from here I am unsure how to proceed. I reckon that I need to define 
$$f(\omega_i, \theta_i) = P_i - \alpha\omega_i + K \underset{i \neq j}{\sum}sin(\theta_i - \theta_j)$$
And:
$$g(\omega_i, \theta_i) = \omega_i$$
And use the RK4 approximation scheme on the two functions, but I can't quite figure out how to do this on a coupled system. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Cheers,

Fabric

Comment: Is in the first equation already $ω_i=\dot θ_i$? What programming language? Are there vector (matrix-algebra) packages available, such as `numpy` in `python`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is conceptual. The important thing to realize is that you have produced a *single* system consisting of, say, $2n$  coupled ordinary differential equations, rather than two coupled systems of $n$ equations each.

You have a vector equation of the form
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\theta} = f(\theta, \dot{\theta})
\end{equation}
and by making the identification $\omega = \dot{\theta}$, you arrive at the system
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} \theta \\ \omega \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \omega \\ f(\theta, \omega) \end{pmatrix} =: F( \theta, \omega)
\end{equation}
If you define a new state vector, say, $x = (\theta,\omega)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, then your new system can be written in the familiar form
\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = F(x), \quad F : \mathbb{R}^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}
\end{equation}
and you can now apply a Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: This is a good answer and makes sense, however I have a hard time recognizing how the "$K \underset{i \neq j}{\sum}\sin(\theta_i - \theta_j)$" fits into the scheme $\dot{x} = F(x)$ as only $\theta_i$ is the relevant coordinate of i'th equation, that is $\dot{x_i} = F(x_i)$. How would I use my runge kutta method on that term? For me it almost looks like the solution is implicit.

Comment: Try writing the different equations out in full for a smallest case which is has the full complexity of the general case, say, $n=3$ angles, $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$. You will a system consisting of six equations.